# Adding Geo-IP data to Query in Access SQL

Tags: sql-server, search, geolocation, ms-access-2010, subquery

Ok this sounds like a problem that someone else should have solved already, but I can't find any help on it, just that their should be a better way of doing it than using an unequal join.

I have a log file of session info with a Source IP, and I am trying to create a query, that actually runs, to combine the Log file with Geo-IP data to tell the DB where users are connecting from. my first attempt came to this:-

```
SELECT coco, region, city
FROM GT_Geo_IP
WHERE (IP_Start <= [IntIP] AND IP_End >=[IntIP])
ORDER BY IP_Start;
```

it seemed to run quite quick and returns the correct record for a given IP. but when I tried to combine it with the log data, like this:-

```
SELECT T.IP,G.coco,G.region, g.city
FROM GT_Geo_IP as G, Log_Table as T
WHERE G.IP_Start <= T.IntIP AND G.IP_End >= T.IntIP
ORDER BY T.IP;
```

it locks access for over 45 mins (pegging one of my cpu cores) before i finally decide i need some CPU back or i should actually have a go at something else. From hunting around and  this is actually slower than i realize, I found [this](http://blog.jcole.us/2007/11/24/on-efficiently-geo-referencing-ips-with-maxmind-geoip-and-mysql-gis/) article and indexed both IP_Start and IP_End to optimize the Search, and based on it came up with this:-

```
SELECT TOP 1 coco, region, city
FROM GT_Geo_IP
WHERE G.IP_Start >= [IntIP]
ORDER BY G.IP_Start;
```

But with my SQL skills i cant work out how to combine it with my log data.

Basically the question is how do i use the better method with my log data to get the required result? or is there a better way to do it?

The GeoIP data is from IP2Location's LITE-DB3

I have thought about nested queries, but i couldn't work out how to construct it, I thought about using VBA, but i'm not sure it will be any quicker

Answer (score 1):

@EnviableOne

Please try this SQL statement.

```
SELECT
L.IP,
(
SELECT TOP 1
CONCAT(coco, ', ', region, ', ', city)
FROM
GT_Geo_IP
WHERE
IP_Start >= L.intIP ORDER BY IP_Start
) AS Location
FROM
Log_Table AS L;
```

Comment: Tried it, Access doesn't like the CONCAT  but i tried just pulling coco and it still runs as slow as the old method. i think the issue is the TOP 1 doesn't work like the LIMIT 1 in MYSQL. I came up with an alternate method, I have a table mapping individual IPs to Geolocations and a VBA script that checks IPs from new records against the table and looks them up if they don't exist and adds it on to the table. Its not scalable but it does for now.

Comment: Ok so I now have 2500 ips in my lookup table and its starting to get a bit slow, does anyone have any other ideas to speed this up in Access 2010?